# Retract of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to open unit ball

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology

I want to know whether the open unit ball $B^2$ is a retract of $\mathbb{R^2}$ or not.

My attempt:

I know if instead of an open unit ball,  I had closed unit ball $D^2$ then I can define a map $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to D^2$ as follows:

$ x \to\begin{cases} 
      x & ||x||\leq 1 \\
      \frac{x}{||x||} & ||x||>1
      \end{cases}$

Which is a retract of $\mathbb{R^2}$ to the closed unit ball. Now somehow I want to generalize this construction for this open unit ball case. Or I want to construct a counterexample to disprove.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Pick any $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ on the unit circle, any sequence $\left(x_n\right)$ in $B^2$ converging to $x$ and assume there were a retraction $f$, then show that $f\left(x_n\right)$ cannot converge to $f(x)$.

Comment: @user23571113, thank you !!

Comment: If $C$ is a retract of a Hausdorff space $X$ then $C$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: @Henno Yes, but an official answer is better than a comnent.

Answer (score 1):

Open unit ball of $\Bbb R^2, B\equiv B(0;1)=\{x\in \Bbb R^2|\Vert x\Vert<1\}$ would be a retract of $\Bbb R^2$, if and only if there existed a continuous map $r:\Bbb R^2\to B$, such that $\forall x\in B:r|_B(x)=x$. We suppose that a retraction $r$ exists. Let $x\in \partial B$; then $r(x)\in B$. Let the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ with $x_{2n-1}:=(1+\frac {1}{2n-1})x,x_{2n}:=(1-\frac {1}{2n})x, n\in \Bbb N$. We observe that $x_{2n+1}\notin B$, $x_{2n}\in B$, for all $n\in \Bbb N$ and $x_n\to x$. Consequently $r(x_{2n})=x_{2n}\to x$, so it must be $r(x_{2n+1})\to x$, from the uniqueness of limit and continuity of $r$. Also by the continuity of $r$ there must be $r(x)=x$. However $x\notin B$ ($B$ is open, so $\partial B\cap B=\varnothing$), so must $r(x)\notin B$, which is false, because $r(\Bbb R^2)\subseteq B$.